# How to softmax two types of labels in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, softmax

TensorFlow is great and we have used it for image classification or recommendation system. We used `softmax` and `cross entropy` as loss function. It works if we have only one type of label. For example, we choose only one digit from 0 to 9 in MNIST dataset.

Now we have the features of gender and age. We have one-hot encoding for each example, such as [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]. The first two labels represent the gender and the last five labels represent the age. Each example has two 1s and the others should be 0s.

Now our code looks like this.

```
logits = inference(batch_features)
softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

But I found that it "softmax" all the labels and sum up to 2. But what I expect is the first two sum up to 1 and the last five sum up to 1. Not sure how to implement that in TensorFlow because these 7(2+5) features seems the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have your gender and age logits concatenated together.

You want the marginal predictions.

You need to split your logits (`tf.slice`) into two arrays and softmax them separately.

Just remember that this only gives you the marginal probabilities.
It can't represent "an old man or a young woman", as this doesn't factorize.

So you might want make joint predictions instead. `5x2` classes instead of `5+2` classes. Obviously this more powerful model is more prone to overfit.

If you have a lot of classes in each category you could build an intermediate model with a low rank factorization of the joint matrix, by adding together multiple marginal predictions. This gives `Nxr+Mxr` entries instead of `N+M` or `NxM`.